# Using rails_api with web-based html rails4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I want make an rails app composed of API part and web based HTML part. And when handling the requests under `/api`, I want rails_api's thin middleware to handle the request for performance optimization, while any other requests being handled by default rails middleware.

What I'm doing currently is, splitting namespace in routes, making controllers for api part and web part inherit `ActionController::API` and `ActionController::Base` respectively.

app/controllers/base_api_controller.rb

```
class BaseApiController < ActionController::API
    ...
end
```

app/controllers/api/projects_controller.rb

```
module Api
  class ProjectsController < BaseApiController
    def index
      ..
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ..
end
```

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ..
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
  resource :projects
end

resource :projects
```

config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/controllers/api
)
```

Now I can get response correctly from `/api/projects`, but when I access `/projects`, I get an error saying

```
Unable to autoload constant ProjectsController, 
expected /app/controllers/api/projects_controller.rb to define it.
```

How can I get this to work? Or what I'm trying to do is impossible in the first place?